# segmentation of elements of a list into sub-groups according to the distance between it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, euclidean-distance

How to subdivide the elements of the list (list of distance ) into groups according to the distance (euclidean-distance where the indices is supposed as angle) between the elements using python like in the example below. where the new lists must start with the starting index in the original list
[image]

PS:
in the Euclidean distance, we need an angle to calculate it. So I supposed that the angle is the indices of list for example list[0]=10
and list[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYmUc.png)=12 to calculate  the Euclidean distance we need first to get  X and Y of each value

```
x1  =  (list[i] * math.cos(math.radians(float(i))))
 
y1 =  (list[i] * math.sin(math.radians(float(i))))

x2  =  (list[i+1] * math.cos(math.radians(float(i+1)))) 

y2=  (list[i+1] * math.sin(math.radians(float(i+1)))) 
distance= sqrt((x1 - x2) * (X - x2) + (posYd - y2) * (posYd - y2))
```

Comment: Can u explain more? I can't understand. I know what's the Euclidean distance. But the relation between indices and the values?

Comment: Did you try it on paper? Sometimes it's better to calculate the algorithms on paper first. I'm a little doubtful about what you wrote here. @Zahra

Comment: Yes, I did... but I can't find an idea to put each values in a different vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this works :

```
import math
# initializing
result = []
vals = [10, 12, 11.5, 12.5, 135, 132, 133, 136, 2, 3, 4, 59, 60, 61, 66, 65, 63, 100, 102, 100]
max_distance = 9

temp = [0]  # Always the first index is zero
for i, val in enumerate(vals):
    if i != len(vals)-1:
        x1 = vals[i] * math.cos(math.radians(float(i)))
        y1 = vals[i] * math.sin(math.radians(float(i)))
        x2 = vals[i + 1] * math.cos(math.radians(float(i + 1)))
        y2 = vals[i + 1] * math.sin(math.radians(float(i + 1)))
        distance = math.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
        # Append the non-zero values
        if int(val) != 0:
            temp.append(val)
        if val != 0 and (distance > max_distance or vals[i+1] == 0):
            # There is 2 condition for ending a cluster
            # if present value !=0 and
            # con 1 : distance > max_distance
            # con 2 : the next value == 0
            result.append(temp)
        if vals[i+1] != 0 and (distance > max_distance or val == 0):
            # There is 2 condition for start a new cluster
            # if next value !=0 and
            # con 1 : distance > max_distance
            # con 2 : the present value == 0
            temp = [i + 1]
    else:
        last = val
temp.append(last)  # The final member
result.append(temp)  # The final cluster

for ls in result:
    print(ls)
```

The result :

```
[0, 10, 12, 11.5, 12.5]
[4, 135, 132, 133, 136]
[8, 2, 3, 4]
[11, 59, 60, 61, 66, 65, 63]
[17, 100, 102, 100]
```

Comment: Sir @Soroosh in order to delete values 0 I have added 
`if val !=0` but  in the first iteration the first case didn't get the right Indice 
`2873.25, 4187.5, 3690.75, 2871.0, 2883.5, 2896.75, 3494.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4544.5, 4420.75, 4330.0, 4525.0` the result was 
`[[0, 2873.25, 2913.5, 2863.25, 2874.75, 2868.5, 2873.25, 4187.5, 3690.75, 2871.0, 2883.5, 2896.75, 3494.5], [12, 4544.5, 4420.75, 4330.0, 4525.0]]` 
but I should get 
`[[0, 2873.25, 2913.5, 2863.25, 2874.75, 2868.5, 2873.25, 4187.5, 3690.75, 2871.0, 2883.5, 2896.75, 3494.5], [18, 4544.5, 4420.75, 4330.0, 4525.0]]`

Comment: Do you mean 16? @Zahra

Comment: And @Zahra What are you replacing with 9? I know that 9 won't work in your new dataset as the last one. What is the new distance limit?

Comment: I use 1700 as distance

Comment: I hope this will be what you want @Zahra : given `[2873.25, 4187.5, 3690.75, 2871.0, 2883.5, 2896.75, 3494.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4544.5, 4420.75, 4330.0, 4525.0]` It will return : `[[0, 2873.25, 4187.5, 3690.75, 2871.0, 2883.5, 2896.75, 0], [13, 4544.5, 4420.75, 4330.0, 4525.0]]` is it ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231610/discussion-between-soroosh-noorzad-and-zahra).